# Installed APK not working locally or on Play store

Tags: android, google-play, onsen-ui, monaca

I built a hybrid Android app with HTML5 an monaca.io IDE. I uploaded the release built successfully on google play but when I install it from the store it does not work, and I cannot find the app icon on my widget, but the app is installed. That also happens when I install the application from my hard disk. I don't know what is is the problem

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.notechsoft.petsbook">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Pets-Book">
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="Pets-Book" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <data android:scheme="tel"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you set your main activity as a launcher activity in the manifest?

Comment: I don;t know how to do that, but when I create the APK file in debugging mode on monaca website and install it, the app works fine

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't ever used Monaca. I have only ever used Eclipse and Android Studio, which are straight up Java. But, the AndroidManifest.xml is the file you should be looking at, in your source code. Also, did you try it in any other device? The problem might be device specific.

Comment: @PratyushYadav I posted the manifest file on the main question please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another intent filter to your AndroidManifest.xml

This is how your new AndroidManifest.xml should look like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.notechsoft.petsbook">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Pets-Book">
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="Pets-Book" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <data android:scheme="tel"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
</manifest>
```

I basically added the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` line in your intent-filter. Recompile with this manifest, and this should get the icon of your app in the app drawer.

Comment: I added it and compile it but I still have the same problem

Comment: Well, then I'm stumped. Maybe someone else would find a solution. Sorry.